# issue with database webhost000, can't find a table

Tags: php, mysql, database, logging, phpmyadmin

I uploaded my site and my database to 000webhost.com, The site is working and so the connection to the database, except  1 table called "users",
All the site is working but when i'm trying to sign in with some user from "users" table in the database it's showing the following error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table
>   or view not found: 1146 Table 'id2302311_pieces1.USERS' doesn't exist
>   (SQL: SELECT * FROM USERS u JOIN users_roles r ON u.id=r.uid WHERE
>   u.email=admin@gmail.com LIMIT 1)

the table exists in the server.
In my local machine it works just fine.

Comment: There is a difference between `USERS` and `users`.

Comment: Linux servers are case sensitive regarding table names. Windows ignores case of those names

Comment: thanks! changed it, it works